# When the PDF asset upload stores dc:title as String array instead String?

Tags: aem

I'm working with AEM and when i upload a PDF as an asset the `dc:title` property in `metadata` sometimes is stored as a `String` and others as a `String[]`.
Is there a criteria for this? when is stored as `String` and when as `String[]`?

Comment: Is PDF a multi-page PDF or single page PDF?

Comment: I've tried with multi-page and single page PDF's and i didn't found any logic on that

Comment: It shouldn't change anything though cause you still should be able to read it the same way. I assume the `String[]` contains only one value. If so, then access to it can be made same as to a pure `String`

Comment: @Phoenix_uy - Were you able resolve this?